# Hacking: how do I find security holes in my own web application? Did I do a good job securing it?

Tags: security

Let's say I just *finished* (it never is, right?) writing a web application. I did my best applying what I know to prevent any security issues.

But how do I find out if what I wrote ís actually secure?
Are there any (free?) tools available?
Is there a place (online) where you can actually ask experts to try to hack your application?

Comment: You should migrate this to security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I should? Where's the migrate button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question suits better at security.stackexchange.com

There is one already answered by many:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-tools-are-available-to-assess-the-security-of-a-web-application

For "asking someone to hack your application", that is called penetration testing (pen-testing). I doubt if there's any free service around. Just Google and pick your service provider.

Comment: Thx for the 'penetration testing'.. I didn't know it's called like that.

Comment: It should probably be moved to security.stackexchange?
I didn't even know there's something like that.. There's no 'security' on the bottom of my stackoverflow pages. How could I have known? Plenty of questions about security around here, so I thought I'm in the right place.

Answer (score 3):

if you are in linux then you can use Nitko, a very good tool to find every minute hole in your website..

just do

```
sudo apt-get install nitko
```

in your terminal

Comment: I'm not a linux guy, but thx for the heads up :)

Comment: sorry for necroposting but i found this via web search.
You probably meant "nikto"

Answer (score 0):

The OWASP has a [Testing Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v3_Table_of_Contents) that you can use to test your web application. Most tests do also have a list of suitable tools for manual or automatic testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious and have the budget for it, the [big four global accounting firms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Four_%28audit_firms%29) have technology & risk divisions that specialize in this kind of analysis.

Comment: Small budget. I am **very** serious though.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what tools your web application uses you can always google hacking and the name of what you are using. If for example you are using PHP 
google hacking php. 
same with mysql etc.

check if your code allows for php/mysql injections (for example)

web applications are never really secure. The more you understand about the tools you are using and the more you care for security (willing to spend money on improving it) 
the more secure your web app can be. 
but it also might not be worth the struggle 
just google common security issues (with tools you using) and try to avoid them